# Why is my jQuery function only running inside another function?

Tags: jquery

So I have this bit of code to pick up a click on a div

```
$("#instructbox").click(function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

however, it only works when I place it inside another function, such as my document.ready function, or oddly enough, any other JS function. I've always wondered about this with jQuery and now I'd like an answer ;p Also, if I place it within a  tag at the bottom of my HTML, it works fine as well.

In full:

```
var words = new Array();
var sylls = new Array();
var csv_file = new Array(); // for word arrays

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "terms.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {processData(data);}
     });

    // generate a haiku!
    $("#instructbox").click(function() {
        alert(writeLine(5));
    });

});



function processData(allText) {
    csv_file = allText.split('\n');

    // csv file is now in an array, split into seperate word array and syllable array
    for (var i = 0; i < csv_file.length; i++) {
        var both = csv_file[i].split(',');  // split at the comma
        words[i] = both[0]; // populate word array
        sylls[i] = both[1]; // populate syllable array
        //put_word(words[i], sylls[i]);
        //alert(words[i]);
    }
    put_word();
};

// put the words into the marquee
function put_word() {
    //console.log(words);
    // place the words into 'words' div
    var divID = document.getElementById("wordlist");    // grab 'words' div
    //divID.innerHTML = words;
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        divID.innerHTML += words[i] + " ";
        //divID.innerHTML += "<span>" + words[i] + "</span>" + "<sup>" + sylls[i] + "</sup> ";
    };
}


function writeLine(syls) {
  var haikuLine = "";
  var sylLeft = syls;

  while ( sylLeft > 0 ) {  // while there are still syllables left
    var rando = Math.floor((Math.random()*300));  // draw a random word
    if (sylls[rando] <= sylLeft) {  // if this random word doesn't take too many syllables
      haikuLine += words[rando] + " ";           // add this to line string, add a space
      sylLeft -=   sylls[rando];            // subtract from syllables left

    }
  }

  return haikuLine;  // toss back finished line
}
```

Comment: Because DOM is not ready at the time when you try to run it as is at the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens, is simple. HTML pages are rendered top to bottom.  Thus, if your script is included as part of a file or in a script tag at the top of the page, then the div with the 'ID' attribute of 'instructbox' which is further down on the page, does not exist on the DOM (Document Object Model) yet.  You need to either, a. put your script or reference to your script file at the bottom of the page so the element in question exists, or b. place your code in the `$(document).ready()` event listener to ensure the document has rendered everything and is ready for you to attach events to it's DOM elements.

Answer (score 3):

If you put the code in your HTML file before the `instructbox` element, then that element won't be in the DOM when the code runs. As a result, `$("#instructbox")` won't find the element, and it won't have anything to add a click handler to.

By putting it in the `$(document).ready()` handler, you ensure that the DOM has been loaded, so the element you want to find will exist and you can bind a handler to it.

Answer (score 1):

It will work on its own if you make sure you place it **after** the HTML to which its referring.

In your case, place the code after the html that creates #instructbox.

Alternatively, follow the best practice and put it inside `document.ready`.

Comment: beautiful, thank you. my next question was going to be "what's best practice?"